# Empty implicit account

Tags: tezos-client

I am running tezos florence 9.1   Ledger nano s synchronizes with ledger live  with balance correct..  On the node the ledger  account address is correct.  But the balance shows as zero  on the node. Node is using path bip25519/0h/0h".
I have cleared the cache, used different accounts and different ledger, but cant resolve this.

Comment: Can you verify that your node is bootstrapped? In other words, it should be at least at block level 1,495,109.

Comment: Definitely bootstrapped.

Comment: If you check the balance of your contract using an indexer, e.g. https://tzstats.com/tz2L9474hvA2EXyNLi4u3YnqrKVf3GzeZ8tb , does it show the correct balance?

Comment: Yes, it shows correct balance. But I’ve just realised that on Florencenet, the node thinks it’s on a testnet and the balance only shows up on mainnet. 
How do I change the node to Mainnet, presuming that’s what I’ve got to do to reconcile node and ledger.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that Florencenet is not mainnet. The former is a [testnet](http://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/test_networks.html#florencenet) for the florence protocol that was used to test florence before it was activated on the mainnet. Now, [florence is activated on mainnet](https://tzstats.com/protocols), so both these networks run the same protocol.

To reinitialize your node to mainnet, you will need to make a new data dir and then bootstrap again (you can use a [snapshot](http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/snapshots.html) to go faster). Basically, following the directions [here](http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/multinetwork.html#builtin-networks) (but you don't actually have to supply the `--protocol` flag as `mainnet` is the default value).

Comment: Thank you very much arvidj, at last I now have a solution for correcting this. YEAH!